# Using StackLayout i want to show only one table on selection of flag

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I have two tables, on flag i need to show one table at a time. My createControl() method is called at the time of loading and flag value is true so one table is loaded first time, when choose of false flag my second table its giving null pointer. because second time table is not called correctly. i seen in google that stacklayout will work for this type of loading which will load two table at the time of load. but i am not able to call them using stacklayout.

```java
 public void createControl(final Composite parent) {
     final Font font = parent.getFont();
     final Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
     composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
     composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));
     composite.setFont(font);

     composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
     composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.DEFAULT, true, false));
     final Composite controlsComposite = WidgetFactory.getClassicToolkit().createComposite(composite);
     final GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(NUM_COLUMN, false);
     controlsComposite.setLayout(gridLayout);
     final GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.DEFAULT, true, true);
     gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
     gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
     controlsComposite.setLayoutData(gridData);

     if (getWizard() instanceof TestWizard) {
         final IWizardPage[] wizardPages = getWizard().getPages();
         for (final IWizardPage page : wizardPages) {
             if (page instanceof PSRDesignerImportWizardPage) {
                 TestWizard importwizardPage = (TestWizard) page;
                 if (importwizardPage.isInitiative()) {
                     setTitle("Table1");
                     setMessage("Hello");
                     gridLayout.numColumns = 1;
                     controlsComposite.setLayout(gridLayout);
                     createTable1Control(controlsComposite);
                     gnerImport = true;
                 } else {
                     setTitle("Table2");
                     setMessage("Bye");
                     controlsComposite.setLayout(gridLayout);
                     createTable2Control(controlsComposite);
                     rDomainImport = true;
                 }
             }
         }

     } else {
         creatFileSelectionGroup(controlsComposite);
     }
     createImportOptions(controlsComposite);
     setControl(composite);
 }
```

code 2:

```java
 @Override
 public IWizardPage getNextPage() {
     List<tualInitiative> ualInitiativeList = getConceptualInitiativeList(psrUserInfo);
     if (ualInitiativeList.isEmpty()) {
         return null;
     }
     IWizardPage nextPage = super.getNextPage();
     if (nextPage instanceof FormatImportWizardPage) {
         FormatImportWizardPage xfPage = (FormatImportWizardPage) nextPage;
         if (initiative) {
             xfPage.settable1Data(ualInitiativeList);  
         } else {
             xfPage.settable2Data(ualInitiativeList);  
         }
     }
     return nextPage;
 }
```

Comment: Hi all i am new to SWT. i have two tables, on flag i need to show one table at a time. my createControl() method is called at the time of loading and flag value is true so one table is loaded first time, when choose of false flag my second table its giving null pointer. because second time table is not called correctly. i seen in google that stacklayout will work for this type of loading which will load two table at the time of load. but i am not able to call them using stacklayout please help me.

Comment: Sorry but it is really hard to follow what you are trying to do. If you want to initialize data in a WizardPage when it becomes visible it is best to do it in the `setVisible` method of the page.

Comment: Hi Greg thank you for your comment, in my case two tables have different data and setVisible is not working for me.